# Find angle x in the picture

Tags: geometry, soft-question

This question is in the form of a picture:

[image]

How long did it take you to find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$15+35+10+80+15+12+30+20+20+40-20-60-10-15-45-30-35-10-5=47?$

Comment: Because $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel, the sum of the upward-facing angles must be equal to the sum of the downward-facing angles. 47 degrees, indeed.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi: Post the proof!!

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi , Thank you! I was lost as to what symmetricuser has done until I read your comment. Wow, learnt something new today, I never knew this was true. Do you know a link that proves this ? Or is there a name for this theorem?

Comment: @symmetricuser Lets see if somebody did it faster. Otherwise, I would mark your answer as the answer. :)